# Why sizeof() of a string variable always return the same number even when content changes?

Tags: c++, sizeof

This is a rather simple problem but is pretty confusing.

```
string R = "hhhh" ;
cout<< sizeof( R )<<endl;
```

OUTPUT:

```
4
```

**Variation:**

string R = "hhuuuuuuhh" ;
cout<< sizeof( R )<

OUTPUT2:

```
4
```

What is going wrong ? Should I use char array instead ?

Comment: Because it is evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Think of `sizeof` being *compile-time* evaluable. It evaluates to the size of the type, not the size of the contents. You can even write `sizeof(std::string)` which will be *exactly* the same as `sizeof(foo)` for any `std::string` *instance* `foo`.

To compute the number of characters in a `std::string`, use `size()`.

If you have a character array, say `char c[6]` then the *type* of `c` is an *array* of 6 `char`s. So `sizeof(c)` (known at compile-time) will be 6 as the C++ standard *defines* the size of a single `char` to be 1.

Comment: `std::string::length()` is equivalent to `std::string::size()`. Depending on the context, `length()` may be preferred for code-readability reasons.

Comment: But what if I want to know the number of bytes instead of the length?

Comment: You mean something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity?

Comment: I think yes as I wanted to know exactly how many bytes I want to receive and send through the serial port. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas Dittmann Rubbish! Why would I use different function for each container type to check its size?

Comment: @Air No. If you need to know the number of bytes to send through port you need size(), not capacity(). Size is givben in units of char which is usually 8 bits, or check out CHAR_BIT if you want to be really sure.

Comment: @Slava If I use the std::string as a "reasonable" **string** in my code and want to know it's length, I use the `length()` function. If I use the std::string as a charbuffer containing **arbitrary chars**, I use `size()`. It just helps a bit to recognize the usage of the std::string variable. It does not make any difference on the executed code. Like I said, I use it contextually dependend to clarify my intention.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof expression` returns the size required for storage of the *type* expression evaluates to (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof). In case of `std::string`, this contains a pointer to the data (and possibly a buffer for small strings), but not the data itself, so it doesn't (and can't) depend on string length.

Answer (score 0):

Your string variable will consist of a part most often stored on the stack, which has fixed dimensions. The size of this part is what's returned by sizeof (). Inside this fixed part is a pointer (or reference) to a part stored on the heap, which actually contain your characters and has a varying size. However the size of this part is only known at runtime, while sizeof () is computed at compile time.

You may wonder why. Things like this are both the strength and the weakness of C++. C++ is a totally different beast from e.g. languages like Python and C#. While the latter languages can produce all kinds of dynamically changing meta-data (like the size or type of a variable), the price that is paid is that they're all slow. C++, while being a bit 'spartan', can run rings around such languages. In fact most 'dynamic' languages are in fact implemented (programmed) in C/C++.